# Setup SonarQube with DB2

Tags: db2, sonarqube

I am trying to setup sonarqube on DB2.

The user I have got created on DB2 doesn't have privileges to create tables/perform DDL operations.

Where can i get the DDLs for DB2?

Answer (score 3):

DB2 is not supported by SonarQube, see [requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) . You'd better pick a supported database rather than going into unknown territory.